# How to get a Geb module instance with its declared class?

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

Up to Geb version 0.10 the example code below has worked just fine:

```
package whatever

import geb.Module
import geb.Page
import geb.spock.GebSpec

class ExampleSpec extends GebSpec {

    def 'MODULE - Y U NO HAVE THE RIGHT CLASS?'() {

        when:
            ExamplePage page = to ExamplePage

        then:
            verifySomething(page.theModule)
    }

    boolean verifySomething(ExampleModule module) {
        // ...
    }
}

class ExamplePage extends Page {

    static content = {
        theModule { module ExampleModule }
    }
}

class ExampleModule extends Module {

}
```

I wanted upgrade to the latest 0.13.1 but apparently the breaking (regressive I would say) change has been introduced which results with:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.verifySomething() is applicable for
>   argument types: (geb.content.TemplateDerivedPageContent) values:
>   [whatever.ExamplePage -> theModule: whatever.ExampleModule]

I've noticed that the same happens but with different class since version 0.11, the exception message is as follows:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.verifySomething() is applicable for
>   argument types: (geb.content.SimplePageContent) values: [theModule -
>   SimplePageContent (owner: whatever.ExamplePage, args: [], value:
>   null)]

Why module declared with a given, specific class looses it at runtime? How to prevent that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects implementing `Navigator` interface (which includes classes extending from `Module`) and returned from content definitions are wrapped with `TemplateDerivedPageContent` objects which delegate to the underlying object but also allow to produce a [meaningful path to the object for error reporting](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/dbd8f89a0677b1413cab0cba2bc9d3629342d58d/module/geb-core/src/test/groovy/geb/ContentToStringSpec.groovy#L33).

The wrapping of modules worked in older versions of Geb, then it got inadvertently removed and now it's back. Even though you can still call all the methods of the module when it's wrapped thanks to `TemplateDerivedPageContent` dynamically delegating to the underlying object you run into trouble in cases like yours - when you want to strongly type your code that uses modules. Therefore I'm still undecided what we should sacrifice here - better error reporting or ability to strongly type and this wrapping might be removed in a future version of Geb.

Luckily there is a workaround - if you want to strongly type code that consumes modules then use a getter instead of a content definition to declare them. In your case it would be:

```
class ExamplePage extends Page {

    ExampleModule getTheModule() {
        module ExampleModule
    }

}
```

Comment: Great, mystery solved. I was just about to search for the breaking commit in Geb repo to understand what's going on. I would rather solve it the way without need of using strong types, but I'm migrating codebase which already have it and it's making migration much bigger to address that. If you care, in my opinion loosing declared type is not great anyway. Wouldn't it be possible to decorate somehow the declared type instance with the wrapper behaviour without hiding the original type?

Comment: That would be ideal and if that was doable then I'd already done it but I don't know how:). We will have to compromise here, the question is what is the best compromise.

Comment: Is there any open discussion about this matter I could contribute to?

Comment: No, there isn't. Feel free to start one on the user mailing list or create an issue in the tracker so that we don't forget about it.

Comment: All right, I did start one: https://github.com/geb/issues/issues/433 There is not much details given though as I haven't investigated the matter yet.

Comment: By the way, is there a way to unwrap a module instance in runtime. Such declared within `static content` closure? Perhaps this would be not a bad compromise for the time being. Not to mention that maybe even it would be possible to implement automatic unwrapping via groovy `as` operator. This way it would be up to the user to decide strong type or better error message for a given use case. Another way which comes to my mind - there could be a Geb config flag to set for the given project whether wrap modules or not.

Comment: This is real pain for our tests :( - Is really necessary to wrap module into TemplateDerivedPageContent? Strong typing is important in my case :(   (now we have geb 1.1.1)

Comment: You can either use the workaround described in my answer or the `as` operator as [described in the manual](http://gebish.org/manual/current/#unwrapping-modules-returned-from-the-code-content-code-dsl).